# Setting up dependency injection for my own classes

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a little problem I can't wrap my head around in relation to Dependency Injections. I learned how to inject dependency for .net mvc 5 controllers using Ninject. However, I can't figure out how to inject dependencies for my own classes.

For example I have a Resource class.

```c#
public class Resource
{
       public IResourceLoader ResourceLoader {get;set}

       public Resource(IResourceLoader ResourceLoader)
       {
              this.ResourceLoader = ResourceLoader; 
       }
}
```

Where IResourceLoader can be implemented to load different types of resources such as XMLLoader. So is it possible to use Ninject to automatically send an instance of XMLLoader when I do

```
Resource xmlResource = new Resource(/*do something here/*);
```

Or better yet if I have a Banner class that inherits from Resource that sets a string resourceType to "xml" and have Ninject filter instances based on that string.

Do I have to implement a factory pattern and do it myself.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The simple use of DI is where you first register your dependencies (Ninject calls this 'type bindings'):

```
Bind<IResourceLoader>().To<XMLLoader>();
```

You can then get an instance of Resource by doing:

```
IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
var resource = kernel.Get<Resource>();
```

and Ninject will wire-up the constructor types it knows about.

Alternatively, there are [several other ways to create dependencies](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Providers%2C-Factory-Methods-and-the-Activation-Context), including, for example the ability to completely control parameters used to create the resource instance:

```
Bind<IResourceLoader>().ToMethod(context => new XMLResourceLoader("schema.xsd"));
```

### Contextual binding

Ninject also supports something it calls [Contextual Binding](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding), where basically you can do something like this:

```
Bind<IResourceLoader>().To<SimpleResourceLoader>();
Bind<IResourceLoader>().To<XMLResourceLoader>().Named("XML");

public class Banner : Resource
{
   public Banner([Named("XML")] IResourceLoader resourceLoader) 
     : base(resourceLoader) { }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the contextual binding was what I was looking for. Just a follow up comment. Wouldn't calling kernel.Get() where my resource is required create a dependency of that module on the DI itself. Would there be a way of decoupling this too?

Comment: @user2119597 At some point, something has to call Ninject. Usually you use DI all the way down, so Resource itself is registered as a dependency and injected into whatever needs it, down to the entry point of the app. All of the DI code should be in one place (though unit tests may also define some dependencies when testing, some of which are mock instances). If you do things right, you'll never need references to your DI container within any other class.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Ninject, and in a web project, you should have a `NinjectWebCommon.cs` class in the `App_Start` folder?

In the `RegisterServices`method you could add:

```
kernel
    .Bind<IResourceLoader>()
    .ToMethod<IResourceLoader>(InstantiateResourceLoader)
```

And then in the same class, implement the method like so:

```
private static IResourceLoader InstantiateResourceLoader(IContext ctx) {
    // Put in whatever logic you need to decide on which loader you want to return
    // Use ctx.Kernel.Get<WhatEver>() if you need something from the DI
    return new XMLLoader();
}
```